# AreaRegistration is not working in MVC Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have added a area called blogging in my site I created all the stuffs and I just tried to access it in the browser by manually entering the Url but I am getting error like "Server Error in '/' Application.". I have attached the code and snapshot of my project. 
Any help would be appreciated.

**Global.Asax**

```
public static void MyCustomRouting(RouteCollection coll)
{
    coll.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    coll.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }, new[] { "Areas.Controllers" });
}

protected void Application_Start()
{
    //RouteDebug.RouteDebugger.RewriteRoutesForTesting(RouteTable.Routes);
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    MyCustomRouting(RouteTable.Routes);
}
```

**BloggingAreaRegistration.cs**

```
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MVC_PageRouting.Areas.Blogging
{
    public class BloggingAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration
    {
        public override string AreaName
        {
            get { return "Blogging"; }
        }

        public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
        {
            context.MapRoute("Blogging_default", "Blogging/{controller}/{action}/{id}", new {action="Index",UrlParameter.Optional });
        }
    }
}
```

**Folder Structure:**

[image: Architecture]

**Error:**

[image: Browser Error]

Answer (score 2):

Specify that your id parameter is optional by adding "id = " to the front of UrlParameter.Optional

```
new {action="Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would bet if went to this url it would work:

```
http://localhost:51803/Blogging/BloggingHome/Index/0
```

The reason is that you have incorrectly specified your MapRoute parameters.  You specified this:

```
new {action="Index", UrlParameter.Optional });
```

You forgot to include the id name, so MVC doesn't know what you mean.  You want this:

```
new {action="Index", id=UrlParameter.Optional });
```

Note the "id=", this tells MVC that id is optional.  Without that, MVC doesn't know what you mean by UrlParameter.Optional, thus it makes the id required.  And since you did not include the id in your URL, no route was selected, and thus a 404 was issued.

Comment: Thanks for your help I forgot to add id i dono how i missed that but however thanks . along with this  I want "Blogging/BloggingHome/Index" this as my start page instead of "/Home/Index" so for that how to configure it in MyCustomRouting

Comment: @my1 - you need to specify the default controller and area, just as you are the action, and you need to do this to the default route.

Comment: I added this "coll.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}", new { controller = "BloggingHome", action = "Index", area = "Blogging" });" in Global.asax but iam getting error as "The view 'Index' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
~/Views/BloggingHome/Index.aspx..."

Answer (score 0):

Can you update your area registration to this and try?

```
context.MapRoute("Blogging_default", "Blogging/{controller}/{action}/{id}", new {controller = "BloggingHome",action="Index",UrlParameter.Optional });
```

Comment: I tried by adding the controller earlier but it isn't working

Comment: Can you move your view to the views folder in the base directory and try. just move your index.html